# How to use polymer core icons inside of an angular.js app..?

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I am using angular.js to build a SPA and angular-material to for the designing the layout. But turns out that angular material icons are not CSS styleable but polymer's icons are. So I want to use polymer icons inside my angular.js app.. I've included `polymer.js` in my scripts and import `core-icons.html` but there is an error..

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'HTML' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolveDom' of undefined
```

How can I use polymer icons inside my angular.js app..??

Comment: what do you mean that md-icons are not styleable but polymer's are ! can you please provide code your are using.

Comment: by the way, [material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) repo is already out there. fyi.

Comment: In polymer, you can add a class to polymer icon 
`<style>
  core-icon[icon="android"] {
    color: #a4c639;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
</style>
<core-icon icon="android"></core-icon>`

but in angular you can't do anything like that.. :/

Comment: i would call it class inheritance. i guess you could use md icons svg/png with in-line style OR css class. Also polymer core-icons are svgs only referenced in their element html files.

Comment: Also i am not sure why you referenced polymer.js for icons. please see [this link](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-icon) if you anyway wants to use core-icons with angular-material.

Comment: Still getting the same error on latest versions of both webcomponents and angular; seems they are not compatible since both need to start up first before touching the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not understand ShadowDOM that Polymer makes extensive use of. So when Angular parses and compiles the HTML it does not know what to do which custom elements so it throws an error.

But from Polymer 0.8 this might change and might be compatible with Angular.

One more thing I notices in your Question was that, you added `polymer.js` instead of `webcomponents.js`. `polymer.js` is the Polymer Library which is used in making new elements and interacting with them, where are `webcomponents.js` is the polyfill for Web components themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I've used polymer icons in an angular project using material angular. In my case I wanted to use the polymer paper-icon-button element as well but I've also done it with just a core-icon element.

I did not need to include polymer.js, just:

polymer.html, core-icon.html, core-icons.html

I used a paper-icon-button so I also included

paper-icon-button.html
and I used am icon from the social set so I included core-icons/social-icons.html as well

for just a core-icon (i had it in a button but i don't think it's necessary)

```
<button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="rp-menu-button">
    <core-icon icon="menu></core-icon>
</button>
```

The CSS (LESS):

```
.rp-menu-button {
    background: none;
    border: none; 
    .rp-menu-icon;
}

.rp-menu-icon {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    color: @toolbar-font-color;
}
```

Or for a paper-icon-button:

```
<paper-icon-button class="rp-card-paper-icon" id="share" icon="social:share">
```

The CSS (LESS):

```
.rp-card-paper-icon {
    text-align: center;
    color: @inactive-icon;
    &:hover {
        color: @active-icon;
    }   
}
.rp-card-paper-icon::shadow core-icon {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

.rp-card-paper-icon::shadow #ripple {
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
}

.rp-card-paper-icon#share::shadow #ripple {
    color: green;
}
```

So You set the color in the class and the size of the icon in .[class]::shadow core-icon and you can use

```
.rp-card-paper-icon::shadow #ripple
```

to style to ripple effect (if you are using a paper-icon-button)